# most elegant way to calculate rowSums of colums that start AND end with certain strings, using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with a dataset of which I want to calculate `rowSums` of columns that start with a certain string and end with an other specified string, using dplyr (in my example: `starts_with('c_')` & `ends_with('_f')`)

My current code is as follows (and works fine):

```
df <- df %>% mutate(row.sum = rowSums(select(select(., starts_with('c_')), ends_with('_f'))))
```

However, as you can see, using the `select()` function within a `select()` function seems a bit messy. Is there a way to combine the `starts_with` and `ends_with` within just one `select()` function? Or do you have other ideas to make this line of code more elegant via using dplyr?

EDIT:
To make the example reproducible:

```
names <- c('c_first_f', 'c_second_o', 't_third_f', 'c_fourth_f')
values <- c(5, 3, 2, 5)
df <- t(values)
colnames(df) <- names
> df
     c_first_f c_second_o t_third_f c_fourth_f
[1,]         5          3         2          5
```

Thus, here I want to sum the first and fourth column, making the summed value 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `select_at` with `matches`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select_at(vars(matches("^c_.*_f$"))) %>% mutate(row.sum = rowSums(.))
```

and with base R :

```
df$row.sum <- rowSums(df[grep("^c_.*_f$", names(df))])
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Do you know where I can find an overview of the different signs you are using in "^c_.*_f$"? I often see people using these things but i'm not sure of what they mean

Comment: @jorangeeraerts Those are regular expressions, you can start reading about them from here https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: maybe you can add an update with `select` and `where`?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse` approaches

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
     select_at(vars(matches("^c_.*_f$")))  %>%
     mutate(rowSum = reduce(., `+`))
```

Or with new versions of `tidyverse`, `select` can take `matches`

```
df %>%
    select(matches("^c_.*_f$")) %>%
    mutate(rowSum = reduce(., `+`))
```

Comment: maybe you can add an update with `select` and `where`?