# How to use an operation in few columns with a specific character in column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to use an operation over a set of columns. All the columns contain a specific word in its name. Here I am attaching my code on `nycflights::airline` dataset. I tried using `starts_with` and `str_detect`. Please let me know what changes can be made to make the program simple. I observed that `starts_with()` works in `select` function only.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

MaxValue <- nycflights13::flights %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(XX = max(dep_time, sched_dep_time, arr_time, sched_arr_time, air_time)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::select(ends_with("_time"), XX)
```

The above program worked but its hard to write all names ending with `_time` in `max()` function.

```
MaxValue <- nycflights13::flights %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(XX = max(str_detect(string = colnames(.), pattern = "_time"))) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::select(ends_with("_time"), XX)
```

The above program did not provide expected output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `nycflights13::flights %>% dplyr::mutate(XX = do.call(pmax, dplyr::across(ends_with("_time")))) %>% ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [most elegant way to calculate rowSums of colums that start AND end with certain strings, using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702767/most-elegant-way-to-calculate-rowsums-of-colums-that-start-and-end-with-certain)